# Help installing Zoiper on Raspbian or a .deb/.run file

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

Can anyone help me instal zoiper (voip) on my raspberry pi 3B+ (Raspbian OS).

I’m having great difficulties and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: You may try https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-zoiper-on-linux/